# Non-constant holomorphic and bounded functions $f:\Omega_j\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Are there holomorphic, non-constant and bounded functions $$f:\Omega_j\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$$
with

1. $\Omega_1=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$
2. $\Omega_2=\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,\infty)$?

Since $\Omega_2$ is star-shaped I can use the Riemann mapping theorem and find a biholomorphic function $f:\Omega_2\rightarrow\mathbb{D}$.

But what about #1? And I have the feeling that using the Riemann mapping theorem is kind of too much here. Are there alternatives?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that my solution of #2 is false?

Comment: @tired : I was temptated to say no too, but David found a counter-example

Comment: @user1952009 yeah indeed..i delete my stupid comment^^

Comment: @user1952009  you were tempted to say no til I found a counterexample? There's a counterexample right there in the OP, just a needlessly sophisticated one.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich yes you r right I'm not very at ease with RMT, should I ?

Comment: @user1952009 The question doesn't quite parse. If you're asking whether you should be at ease with RMT, well of course "should" depends on what you're trying to accomplish, but if you want to know basic complex analysis then yes, you certainly need to know RMT very well, it's one of the big deals.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich did you prove the RMT in details ? (everybody says it is far to be easy, as say the great Picard theorem)

Comment: @user1952009 Of course I've proved it in detail. It's proved in detail in any decent book on complex analysis (including mine, _Complex Made Simple_). It's not at all trivial, but it's much easier than the big Picard theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1).  If $f:\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb C$ is analytic and bounded so by Riemann's theorem , $z=0$ is a removable singularity of $f$. After removing it $f$ is an entire function. So by Liouville's theorem $f$ is constant.

Comment: $e^z$ is bounded in $\Omega_2$??? Since $\Omega_2$ is dense, n example for (2) cannot be the restriction of an entire function...

Comment: Is $e^z$ unbounded in $\Omega_2$? How ?

Comment: This is ridiculous. It's obviously unbounded. Not that a proof is needed, but my first comment contains a proof that it MUST be unbounded - would you like me to type that again? It's not hard to find the error in what you wrote...

Comment: For $z=x+iy$, $x$, $y$ real, we have $|e^z|=|e^x||e^{iy}|=e^x$. As $x\rightarrow\infty$ the modulus also goes to infinity.

Comment: @Joey Zou ) Why you take $x\to \infty$ ? See the domain.

Comment: With $z=x+iy$, $x$ is the real part of $z$. There are plenty of points in $\mathbb{C}\backslash [0,\infty)$ with large real parts. :)

Answer (score 5):

For (2) without the Riemann mapping theorem, note that there's a branch of $\log(z)$ defined in $\Omega_2$. And the imaginary part of the logarithm is bounded, so ... is a bounded holomorphic function.

Comment: So my answer using the Riemann mapping theorem is right?

Comment: @N.Sch Yes, but you're right, it's easier than RMT. (There's no way to downvote a comment...)

Comment: Okay and what function maps the image of the logarithm in a bounded set?

Comment: @N.Sch do you know a function $h(z)$ whose modulus depends only on $Re(z)$ ?

Comment: @N.Sch You don't want me to have _all_ the fun. The imaginary part is bounded. So you just need to find a function bounded in a certain _strip_. There are lots of those...